# Jquery BlockUI in IEMobile (Windows Phone) :content is not getting blocked

Tags: jquery, html

We are developing a hybrid windows phone app and are using `Jquery BlockUI` to block the content of the UI while calling `Ajax`. The problem is that on windows phone `BlockUI` doesn't prevent clicking elements on the back screen.

How can we make block UI work on Windows Phone?

Comment: same issue here, contents under elements that are `position:fixed` can be clicked